Blazor 8 Interactive Server Authentication System Refresh Cookie
I am using Dot Net 8 Blazor Interactive server with default authentication provided by the template.
The default authentication template uses IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider and a default setup.
I tinkered around a bit, and after setting application cookie expire time to 1 min and RevalidationInterval to 1 min also, to see what happens - I found out that unless I refresh the page, the cookie is being deleted from the application cookie storage, but the user is not being logged out or (with viewed through debug) is being kept IsAuthenticated to true.
How would I go about either refreshing, or on page navigation, if the cookie is gone or timed out, logout the user.
Edit:
My auth state:
 internal sealed class 
 IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
     ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
     IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
     IOptions<IdentityOptions> options)
 : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider(loggerFactory)
{
 protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

 protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
     AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
     await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
     var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
     return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
 }

 private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
 {
     var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
     if (user is null)
     {
         return false;
     }
     else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(options.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
         var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
         return principalStamp == userStamp;
     }
 }        
}

my cookie configuration
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
.AddIdentityCookies(o =>
{
    
})
; 
 builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;     
});

It is worth noting that all my pages are Interactive including the Nav menu, login menu. I am achieving login and logout using a middleware.

To ensure the user is logged out or reauthenticated when the application cookie expires, you need to properly handle the authentication state in your Blazor Server application. The default setup with IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider should revalidate the authentication state at the specified interval. However, it seems there is a discrepancy in your case, and additional steps might be necessary to address this. Could you pls share enough code to reproduce your issue?

I updated the post with code. Please have a look when you have time

@Muheeb have you solved this?

@Marmellad unfortunately no.
